# React return component on click if true or false

Tags: reactjs

I have a code editor where I would enter print("Hello World") and pushing the button checks if it's correct or not using regex.

The issue I'm getting now is loading in a Success or Fail component when the button is clicked. When I console.log a success or fail message it works. Just looking to load in actual components now to show the user if the input was right or wrong.

```
function Code(props) {
  const [showResults, setShowResults] = React.useState(false);

  const propsValue = props.value;

  const codeValue = useRef();

  function handleChange() {
    const string = codeValue.current.editor.getValue();
    const regex = /^(print\(("|')?hello\sworld!?("|')\))$/gi;
    const match = regex.exec(string);

    if (match) {
      setShowResults(true);
      return <Success />;
    } else {
      return <Fail />;
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ReactAce
        ref={codeValue}
        value={propsValue}
        mode="python"
        theme="github"
       />

      <button className="btn" onClick={handleChange}>
        Run Code
      </button>

    </>
  );
}

export default Code;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you do the test, you can call `setState` with either Success or Fail, then have it get rendered the next time the component runs:

```
function Code(props) {
  const [showResults, setShowResults] = React.useState(false);
  const [msgComponent, setMsgComponent] = React.useState(null);

  const propsValue = props.value;

  const codeValue = useRef();

  function handleChange() {
    const string = codeValue.current.editor.getValue();
    const regex = /^(print\(("|')?hello\sworld!?("|')\))$/gi;
    const match = regex.exec(string);

    if (match) {
      setShowResults(true);
      setMsgComponent(<Success />);
    } else {
      setMsgComponent(<Fail />);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ReactAce
        ref={codeValue}
        value={propsValue}
        mode="python"
        theme="github"
       />

      <button className="btn" onClick={handleChange}>
        Run Code
      </button>
      { msgComponent }
    </>
  );
}
```

Insert the `{ msgComponent }` into wherever you want the new component to be in the HTML.

When you want to clear the Success or Fail, do `setMsgComponent(null)`. You could also add a `setTimeout` to clear it 5 seconds after it gets rendered, for example.